# Creating a new file with both a subset of data and file names from a group of .csv files

Tags: r, csv

My issue is likely with how I'm exporting the data from the for loop, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've got over 200 files in a folder, all structured in the same way, from which I'd like to pull the maximum number from a single column.  I've made a for loop to do this based off of code from here http://www.r-bloggers.com/looping-through-files/

What I have running so far looks like this:

```
fileNames<-Sys.glob("*.csv")

for(i in 1:length(fileNames)){

   data<-read.csv(fileNames[i])
   VelM = max(data[,8],na.rm=TRUE)

   write.table(VelM, "Summary", append=TRUE, sep=",",
       row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)

}
```

This works, but I need to figure out a way to have a second column in my summary file that contains the original file name the data in that row came from for reference.

I tried making both a matrix and a data frame instead of going straight to the table writing, but in both cases I wasn't able to append the data and ended up with values from only the last file.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would recommend to improve your current method, also going with `fread()` because it's very fast and has the `select` argument.  Notice I have moved the `write.table()` call outside the `for()` loop. This allows a cleaner way of adding the new column of file names alongside the max column, and eliminates the need to append to the file on every iteration.

```
library(data.table)

fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
VelM <- numeric(length(fileNames))

for(i in seq_along(fileNames)) {
    VelM[i] <- max(fread(fileNames[i], select = 8)[[1L]], na.rm = TRUE)
}

write.table(data.frame(VelM, fileNames), "Summary", sep = ",",
    row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I actually like this approach because it doesn't retain the entire column, just the max value from each file.  This could be a more efficient use of memory.  Unless you want the ability to do other stuff with the entire column (like mean, median, etc.) that you didn't know about at the time of reading the file..

Comment: for style, one could also use `sapply` instead of the for loop: `VelM <- sapply(fileNames, function(fn){max(fread(fn, select=8)[[1]], na.rm=TRUE)})`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quickly read files, you should consider using `data.table::fread` or `readr::read_csv` instead of base `read.csv`.

For example:

```
fileNames <- list.files(path = your_path, pattern='\\.csv') # instead of Sys.glob

library('data.table')  

dt <- rbindlist(lapply(fileNames, fread, select=8, idcol=TRUE))

dt[, .(max_val = max(your_var)), by = id]

write.table(dt, 'yourfile.csv', sep=',', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

**Explanation:** `data.table::fread` reads in only the `select=8`th column from each file (via `lapply` to `fileNames`, which returns a list of data.tables).  Then `data.table::rbindlist` combines this list of data.tables (of one column each) into a single data.table, producing an additional column `idcol`.  From `?fread`, note that

> If input is a named list, ids are generated using them

Because `lapply` returns a named list with each name being the element of `fileNames`, this is an easy way of passing `fileNames` index for grouping.

The rest is data.table syntax.  It wasn't clear from your question if there is a header row and whether you know the heading in advance.  If so, you can either keep `header=TRUE` and use the header name for `your_var`, or you can do `skip=1, header=FALSE, col.names = 'your_var'`.